# ArcGIS Rest service is returning multiple identical records when getting KMZ

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-rest-api, kmz

This REST URI returns 299 identical records:

```
http://dec.alaska.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EH/Solid_Waste_Sites/MapServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=kmz
```

However if you have it return JSON or HTML, you get the distinct records:

```
http://dec.alaska.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EH/Solid_Waste_Sites/MapServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html
```

This was also happening with layer 0 and I somehow got it to stop by recreating the URI from the query form. I am now using the identical URI with just a different layer id and geometry type - layer 0 is point and layer 1 is polygon. I have also tried recreating the URI from the query form.

It appears that the server is using ArcGIS 10.31.

The server is back up but problem is still there. I should clarify that each record has a unique geometry, but the data fields (ObjectID, Site_ID, Comments, Site Name) are the same on every record in the KMZ. When getting the HTML or JSON the data fields are correct.

Update: I just found a second server, this one at the EPA, that is doing the same thing. The geometries are unique but the data, OBJECTID and PGM_SYS_ID is the same for every record. Here is the URI to get the KMZ:

```
https://geodata.epa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OEI/FRS_INTERESTS/MapServer/27/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=PGM_SYS_ID&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnTrueCurves=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=kmz
```

The EPA server also says it is v10.31.

Comment: Ah! I am getting distinct value for output formats(kmz,json,html,AMF) rather then setting the parameteter `returnDistinctValues=true`

Comment: So no one else had a problem with it, it was working for them? I checked back to the server today and it appears to be down entirely, maybe that was the problem? If either of those was the case, saying so would have been much more helpful than putting it on hold with a canned response which does not tell me anything useful.

Comment: @Slslam, Yeah, I tried that too, maybe the problem was fixed on the server end by the trme you got to it? Of course now the server is down entirely so I cannot find out!

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with more details at any time.  As long as you edit within about a week the act of you editing will move it into the review queue for re-opening.

Comment: @PolyGeo. Thanks, I am learning! It seems though that the question rolls down the list and gets less attention while it is in pergatory. Or does it get a bump from the status change?

Comment: Every edit bumps it. Unlike a discussion forum and other Q&A sites there is no purgatory here. To keep a question alive you just need to keep improving it.  Most importantly, remember that we are not a support site and all potential answerers are volunteering their time so you need to try and make what you are doing, what you have tried and where you are currently stuck as clear as possible in order to attract their attention to your rather than another question.

Comment: Looks like `BUG
-000088575 ` addressed at 10.4.1 "Running a query from REST with the output format set to KMZ 
generates an output which duplicates the parameter, resulting in 
duplicate attributes" http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/104-IssuesAddressedList.pdf

Comment: @KirkKuykendall That comment looks worthy of providing as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in ArcGIS Server.  It was fixed for ArcGIS 10.4.

From http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/104-IssuesAddressedList.pdf :

> **BUG-000088575** 
>   Running a query from REST with the output format set to KMZ
>   generates an output which duplicates the parameter, resulting in
>   duplicate attributes.

You would have to contact Esri Support (or your local reseller) to determine if there's a fix for 10.3.1, or if upgrading is the only way to resolve the issue.